# Вывод чекбокса в админке Вордпресс для работы комментариев

Tags: wordpress

Помогите вывести комvентарии.

По стандарту есть в ВП чекбокс, который разрешает вывод комментариев. В моем случае в теме сделан вывод постов кастомно, то есть коряво, и чекбокса, который разрешает вывод комментариев, - нет. В функцию подключал разные функции для разрешения комментирования, но они не помогают.

Например, такую:

```
function default_comments_on( $data ) {
    if( $data['post_type'] == 'your_custom_post_type_name' ) {
        $data['comment_status'] = 'open';
    }
    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'default_comments_on' );
```

Но, увы, не помогает.

Очень нужна ваша помощь. Может, есть какой-то хук?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Только что проверил данный хук - он работает при условии, что при регистрации кастомного поста была включена поддержка комментариев, а именно:

```
$args = array(
    "supports" => array( "comments" ),
);

register_post_type( "your_custom_post_type_name", $args );
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня все равно не работает, возможно, что то не правильно в самом функционале шаблона.

Comment: Буду разбираться...

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае решение данной проблемы было таким:

Найти все посты (и посты таксономии созданные кастомно) в базе данных и заменить в таблицах в колонке `'comments'` с `'close'` на `'open'`.

И все появляется в админке так как нужно :)